# get distinct values in elastic search for given filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get distinct fields in an index for given filter, for eg
for the below data

```
|Name      |Age |Country|Amount|
================================
|Alfreds   |34  |Germeny|100   |
--------------------------------
|Andrew    |43  |U.K    |333   |
--------------------------------
|Raj       |54  |India  |4553  |
--------------------------------
|John      |43  |U.K    |325   |
--------------------------------
|Ana       |32  |Mexico |56    |
--------------------------------
|Christina |22  |Sweden |345   |
```

I want to have a distinct country name when say, the amount is greater than 300.

What is the best possible way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested only in getting number of distinct values you can use field aggregation:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "amount": {
        "gt": 300
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs" : {
    "uniq_country" : {
      "terms" : {"field" : "country"}
    }
  }
}
```

The query above will give you the following result:

```
"aggregations": {
    "uniq_country": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "u.k",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "india",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "sweden",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```